# Metric on Power Set

Tags: metric-spaces

Let (S, d) be a metric space. Can one always define a metric d# on the power set P(S) of $S$ such that d# ({x} , {y}) = d(x, y) for every x, y ∈ S?

Comment: Yes, the Hausdorff distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

Comment: @JeanMarie then $d$ has to be bounded for $d_H$ to be well-defined. And it's not a metric on all subsets (closedness is minimally needed). E.g. on $[0,2]$ the metric is bounded and $d_H((0,1),[0,1])=0$ while the sets are different.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma You are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Pick $x_0\in S$ and define
$$d^\#(A,B)=\begin{cases}d(a,b)&\text{if }A=\{a\}, B=\{b\}\\
1+d(x_0,b)&\text{if }|A|\ne1, B=\{b\}\\
1+d(a,x_0)&\text{if }A=\{a\},|B|\ne1\\
2&\text{if }|A|\ne1, |B|\ne1, A\ne B\\
0&\text{if }|A|\ne 1, B=A
\end{cases} $$

Essentially, we define the distance between singletons as desired, and the distance of all other sets to $\{x_0\}$ as $1$, and everything else from a "path" via $\{x_0\}$.

Answer (score 4):

This question [Does every metric on a non empty set have an extension to an arbitrary super set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766906/does-every-metric-on-a-non-empty-set-have-an-extension-to-an-arbitrary-super-set/1766961#1766961) is related, since you can embed $S$ into $P(S)$ as 
$S\simeq P_1(S)$

Note there the beautiful solution given by @dtldarek: that basically makes from two metric spaces $X$, $Y$, a metric space on $X\sqcup Y$; intuitively it takes two basic points $x_0\in X$, $y_0\in Y$, and joins $X$, $Y$ by a stick with ends $x_0$, $y_0$, of some length $\delta>0$. The distance $d(x,y)= d_X(x,x_0) + \delta + d_Y(y_0, y)$, the idea being that all traffic between $X$ and $Y$ is channeled through $x_0$ and $y_0$.